# Webpack не видит соединение Localhost:3010

Tags: webpack

Стараюсь настроить webpack dev server. Ошибка: Connection refused: localhost:3010.

"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },

```
  const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
// const argv = require('yargs').argv;

const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash'); 


const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  entry: {
    main: '../src/common.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',    
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    sourceMapFilename: 'error.js.map'
  },  
  module: {
    rules:[
          {
            test:/\.css$/,
            use:['style-loader','css-loader']
          }
       ]
  },  
  devServer: {
    watchContentBase: true,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    port: 3010,
    overlay: true,
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    proxy: {
      '/': "http://localhost:3010",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  },
  devtool: "eval",
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),    
    new ManifestPlugin()   

  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Буду признателен за любой совет

Comment: Webpack не видит соединение Localhost:`3010`
Ошибка: Connection refused: localhost:`3030`.

Comment: Исправил но ошибка осталась